# How to install maven on microsoft Azure (app servies)

Tags: java, maven, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have an app service, hosted on Azure.

The code for our service is on bitbucket and it is a maven based Java project. The process adopted by developers to deploy WAR files is to build them on local and FTP it to Azure which obviously isn't recommended.

Let's say I don't have the liberty and resource for hosting a CI tool like Jenkins, I am trying to do the following:

1. Sync the code from bitbucket.org to Azure by using 'Deployment Options' in Azure. Every time I do a git push, Azure automatically picks up the code from the specified branch and copies/updates/deletes the files modified (and places them under wwwroot by default)
2. I want to modify the deployment.cmd file in Azure so that I can add my custom steps post #1.

Where am I stuck?

1. I have FTPed maven and unpacked maven under `D:\home\maven` folder. I have set the correct environment variables by using a XDT file (attached). Yet, when I do mvn -version, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/maven/exception/ExceptionHandler
>
> ..
>   ..
>   caused by ClassNotFound ..

I don't have the complete trace handy. This class is there in maven-core which is there under the lib folder (I verified).

Could it be because of permissions? Cloud is cloudy to me o_O

2. After I get this to work, I need to add custom steps to deployment.cmd. Is there any specific language which I need to use or windows commands?

XDT file content for env variables (`JAVA_HOME` is already set)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-   Transform"> 
<system.webServer> 
<runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
<environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">      
<add name="M2_HOME" value="D:\home\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9"  xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
<add name="MAVEN_HOME" value="D:\home\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
<add name="Path" value="%Path%%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
</environmentVariables>
</runtime> 
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue, but failed. According to the kudu wiki page for [Xdt transform samples](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples), the environment variables seems not support reference each other which had been defined above the current environment varable.

So please change the XDT file content like below that works fine after I test on an Azure Web App instance for Java.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <add name="M2_HOME" value="D:\home\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
        <add name="MAVEN_HOME" value="D:\home\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
        <add name="PATH" value="%PATH%;D:\home\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
      </environmentVariables>
    </runtime> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Then I ran the command `mvn -version` on Kudu CMD tool, it works fine.